# Testing two targets with same tests

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I had a project with 3 targets:

1. The app target
2. Unit tests target (host app >> 1.)
3. UI tests target (target app >> 1.)

Now, after I added a new app target for a different branding (with slight changes):

1. The app target
2. The new app (new branding)
3. Unit tests target (host app >> 1.)
4. UI tests target (target app >> 1.)

I realised that the unit and UI tests have specific target applications. For the new app, 90% of the tests will be the same. Is there a way to setup the test targets to run twice, once for each of my apps/brandings? (maybe with extern tools?)

Comment: Try to go in your scheme settings, under the Test section. Maybe you can "check" the common test. But I did never tried

Comment: @bobby I already tried that.. it did not work

Comment: Do the two apps have different bundle IDs?

Comment: @Oletha yes, they do

Comment: @Daniel, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really, I had to change the target app while testing. You probably can automate it if you use jenkins or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I found out that what I needed was different targets.

These are my targets now:

1. The app target
2. The new app (new branding)
3. Unit tests target (host app >> 1.)
4. UI tests target (target app >> 1.)
5. Unit tests target (host app >> 2.)
6. UI tests target (target app >> 2.)

Comment: So using this approach you're writing tests for two app targets?

Comment: Sad to hear that. That's kinda overcoding to support two or even more test targets tbh.

Comment: Not really, since you only have to create additional targets, you can share the code though. So for example 3 & 5 could use the same test classes/files

Answer (score 0):

To run the tests (or any subset of tests) twice against different apps, you will need two schemes, and you will need to invoke them separately.

If you want this to be a single-action process, create one scheme for each target app with the correct tests selected to run, then create a shell script that runs tests for those two schemes, one after the other. Then you can just run the script to have tests run against both apps.

To simplify the `xcodebuild` command, you can use [Scan](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/scan), and to automate the process, you can use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io) to run your script on a regular basis, or on triggers like a new commit being pushed to your repository.

Scan works nicely with multiple schemes - add them both to the Scanfile and then have your shell script run them sequentially. In Ruby:

```
`scan --scheme "SchemeOne"`
`scan --scheme "SchemeTwo"`
```

Comment: The problem is, that I cannot select the target app of the test targets in the scheme

Comment: Can you select the executable in the Run menu of the scheme editor (instead of Test)? I can select from my iOS and WatchOS apps.

Comment: Yes, but it does not influence the test target

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386738/daniel) stated you can use the same files in 2 different test targets.  I am attempting this now, I will let you know how it goes.  I found the info at the tutorial below:

[Tutorial on using same files from 2 test targets](https://medium.com/@rijalab/how-to-use-one-test-target-files-for-two-app-targets-in-ios-37df53265a5)